# Modified Flood Fill algorithm produces an Image StackOverflowError

Tags: java, image, png, flood-fill

I am writing a function to fill the edge of an area with another color. Basically, if I have a black donut with a white inside on a PNG and tell it to fill the center, the edge between the black and white should be another color, red in my test.

'''

```
public static void edgeFill(BufferedImage img, int x, int y, Color findColor, Color replaceColor, ArrayList<coordinate> visited) {
        if (x<0 || x>img.getWidth() || y<0 || y>img.getHeight()) { return; }
        if (visited.contains(new coordinate(x,y))) { return; }
        if (img.getRGB(x, y) != findColor.getRGB()) {
            img.setRGB(x, y, replaceColor.getRGB());
            return;
        }
        visited.add(new coordinate(x,y));
        edgeFill(img, x-1, y, findColor, replaceColor, visited);
        edgeFill(img, x+1, y, findColor, replaceColor, visited);
        edgeFill(img, x, y-1, findColor, replaceColor, visited);
        edgeFill(img, x, y+1, findColor, replaceColor, visited);
    }
```

'''
img is a BufferedImage object of a png file (200x200).
int x and y are the start cords.
Color findColor is the color to find to be made a border around (white).
Color replaceColor is the boarder color (black).
visited is a arraylist of coordinates the function has been to.

When I run it, it produces the error
'''

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.desktop/java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel.getRGB(ComponentColorModel.java:1132)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(BufferedImage.java:917)
    at main.floodFillTesting.edgeFill(floodFillTesting.java:36)
```

'''

floodFillTesting.java:36 is the if(img.getRGB()...) line.
I also have a recursive floodFill method that works just fine

'''

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class coordinate {
    private int x,y;
    public coordinate(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    public int getX() { return this.x; }
    public int getY() { return this.y; }
    
    public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
    public void setY(int y) { this.y = y; }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object O) {
        Coordinate o = (Coordinate) O;
        if (o.getX() == this.getX() && o.getY() == this.getY()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

'''
Example of error
'''

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\johns\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Other\\EU4 Mod\\test.png");
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
        edgeFill(img, 200, 200, new Color(255,255,255), new Color(255,0,0), new ArrayList<Coordinate>());
        
        file = new File("C:\\Users\\johns\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Other\\EU4 Mod\\test_mod.png");
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", file);
```

'''
[image: test image input]
[image: test output image, expected output, 1 pixel wide red on border]
edit: added Coordinate class
edit2: added example

Comment: Please provide the implementation of `coordinate` class... Have you implemented its `equals` method? Also `x` in your code is allowed to be equal to `img.getWidth()` (same for `y` to `img.getHeight()`).

Comment: I've added the coordinate class; I did implement the Equals method before posting

Comment: There is a missmatch with the `Coordinate` class posted along with the `coordinate` class used in the `edgeFill` method (the first letter is different in those classes)... Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: The capital is no issue, its lowercase. Will provide minimal example in a second.

Comment: I just realized the stack trace printed when running your program is about 1024 method calls deep, which doesn't sound like much, given the image size... Tested it with a smaller image (a 25 by 25 one) and it worked just fine. Maybe the stack depth is too short for such dimensions.

Comment: I just tested the image with sizes 25x25, 50x50, and 200x200, and they all work fine. So you are right, it's a stack size issue, so for what I'm working on, it should be fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't think it's correct reasoning to say the method works for small data - to throw it to some system stack. Your method is faulty it's a rickety thickety hatch. I won't look  at it since you said you are satisfied but I would if I were you. You owe it to yourself as an upstanding citizen